# Adding functionality to submit button within validation form - Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I know this is a simple fix but through multiple google searches, I can't seem to find the answer to my question. I'm using a validation form from bootstrap 4, and I'm just trying to add functionality to my button by simply linking it to a different page. I tried using the anchor tag,

i.e. `<a href="www.mysite.com" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Submit</a>`

which will work, but the obviously validation is bypassed.

so currently I have this button within a form:

```
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Submit form</button>

</form>
```

with this java script:

```
<script>
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
```

What needs to be added to the js to make the button functional?? Thank you for any assistance!!

Comment: make the button functional?? what functionality you want to add with button?

Comment: sorry, I thought I specified. I just want to link it to another page

Comment: Why not use the form action?

Comment: Why `Array.prototype.filter.call` is used for a simple form validation ? Also only when the button is clicked is where you fetch all from elements and start checking them then if one  if not valid you stop everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version, the code is heavily commented.

```js
// wait for page to load then run the code inside 
window.onload = () => {
  // Select the form we want to validate
  let form = document.querySelector('form');

  // listen for submit event
  form.onsubmit = (event) => {
    // prevent the form from posting so the page won't refresh
    event.preventDefault();
    // debugging log statememnet  (not needed)
    console.log('Form submitted')
    // checking for form validation
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      // if we're inside this if statement, the form is invalid
      // we add the boostrap class to handle styling
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
      // debugging log statememnet  (not needed)
      console.log('Form not valid')
    } else {
      // if we're inside this if statement, the form is valid and ready for further actions
      // debugging log statememnet  (not needed)
      console.log('Form valid')
      // redirect to the target page
      location.href = "www.example.com"
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" value="" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">
        Looks good!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <label for="validationCustomUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Please choose a username.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

If you're a beginner i suggest you stay away from libraries and just play with vanilla js/css build everything from scratch if you get stuck your research on every single line of code, Then and only then you can start messing with libraries and such.